# How to change the apk filename in Android Studio with gradle-plugin 7.2.2 gradle version 7.3.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

i'm using Android Studio Version 2021.2.1
Gradl 7.3.3 and the gradle-plugin 7.2.2

When i try to change the apk-filename in the same way as i have done it in earlier projects
i recieve the following error.

Build file '...\app\build.gradle' line: 34

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AgpDslLockedException: It is too late to add new build types
> They have already been used to configure this project.
> Consider moving this call to finalizeDsl or during evaluation.

I cannot find out what i have to change to give the apk-file a new filename.
Everything i found is for older gradle versions where my build.gradle is working.
Is there a tutorial or howto that helps me to solve the problem.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1205
        versionName '1.2.05'
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'pass'
            storeFile file(mykeystore.jks')
            storePassword '12345'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all { output ->
                    project.ext { appName = 'myAppname' }
                    def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss')
                    // NEXT IST LINE 34 where the ERROR points to
                    def newName = "${globalScope.project.name}-${output.baseName-${variant.versionName}}.apk"
                    newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-") 
                    newName = newName.replace("-release", "-release-" + formattedDate + "_" + versionName.replace(".",""))
                    outputFileName  = new File("../../../../release/" + newName)
                }
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            zipAlignEnabled true
            pseudoLocalesEnabled true
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            //useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
            pseudoLocalesEnabled true
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
buildTypes {

        debug {
            debuggable true
        }

        release {
//            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    def date = new Date()
                    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyy-MM-dd')
                    outputFileName = "${variant.productFlavors[0].name}"  + formattedDate + "_${variant.name}_${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you miss a "}"

on this line

```
def newName = "${globalScope.project.name}-${output.baseName-${variant.versionName}}.apk"
```

the right line must be like this

```
def newName = "${globalScope.project.name}-${output.baseName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
```

That will be enough to solve your issue. At least it works for me

Comment: it is not a "missed" but "misplaced" curly braces ;)